# Angular timeout before routing

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-routing, rxjs5

After update of contact I will show a message and after 1500ms I will route to another page. I did it like this:

```
onSubmit() {
    if (this.form.valid) {            
        this.contactService.updateContact(this.contact).subscribe(response => {
            this.contactUpdated = true;
                Observable.interval(1500)
                  .subscribe(i => { 
                    this.router.navigate(['/commit']); 
                 })
              });
            }
          }
```

This works only once, after I will navigate with mouse to another menu, I will be automatically routed back to the commit route.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Again what doesn't work? You create `Observable.interval` to redirect the user every 1.5s to `/commit`? That's what you want or don't want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So the problem is that you want to redirect the user just once after 1500ms and not every 1500ms and even when the user is already on a different page.

`Observable.interval` emits a value after every interval so you could use `take(1)` to complete the chain after a single emission:

```
Observable.interval(1500)
  .take(1)
  .subscribe(i => { 
     this.router.navigate(['/commit']); 
  })
```

Or even easier you can use `Observable.timer(1500)` that emits just once (if you use only the first parameter):

```
Observable.timer(1500)
  .subscribe(i => { 
     this.router.navigate(['/commit']); 
  })
```

Comment: I receive warning "TS2339: Property 'timer' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'." with Your code, so I have used
`import {timer} from 'rxjs';`
```timer(1500).subscribe(i => {
      this.router.navigate(['/commit']);
    })```

Comment: yes, this answer was for older RxJS versions